# Making a 10x22 ft billboard in AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, document-setup, billboard

I was asked to do a Billboard design that is 10 X 22 feet for a fashion brand that I'm interning for. **I do not have experience** in this kind of stuff, I use AI for fashion flats and vector illustrations, I don't do print work. I did do 2 posters for the internship, but that was easy because I used a template and just added the art work, they came out beautiful!

However, this time, I was unable to find a 10 X 22 billboard AI template. How to set up the document, what numbers do I plug in and do I use inches or centimeters?

Also the images I'll be using is a 150 resolution, is that ok? Don't they need to be 300 dpi?

Comment: I edited your question to remove ALL CAPS, that's considered shouting in writing.

Comment: Yes, I know all caps mean shouting in writing, I'm freaking out here, so yes, I'M SHOUTING, because I HAVE NO EXPERIENCE and need help ASAP! I'm a person that expresses thyself, sir.

Answer (score 0):

10 x 22 ft is 120 inches x 264 inches.
Illustrator have a 227" limit,
but you can create half sized document at 300 PPI so the printing company can do the resizing for 120" x 264" 150 PPI.

New Document -> More settings:
60" x 132" 300 PPI Color mode CMYK

(Please don't shout when you seeking answers, it's unprofessional)

Comment: Illustrator has no DPI setting for documents!

Comment: Illustrator also has no PPI sertting for documents. So stop perpetuating a misundesrtanding of how things actually work. The setting you have does not do what you think it does.

Comment: OK, sorry. I mean when she export the document for TIFF or PNG. Right?

Comment: Perhaps you means that but thats not what you say. Ine either case why would you submit a TIFF or PNG when you can easily send a PDF, that to all intent and purposes is better. However also dont blindly go double this size, ask the vendor they probably have a standard solution to this use that it has less chance of failure.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, I'm going to save the file as a PDF, the designer asked for a pdf and a AI file to get it printed. But, what would be the numbers for the bleed lines and what not? Should I put the bleed at 0.3 or .125 for the trim line and .25 for the live area?

Comment: Bleeds and trim marks are entirely a consideration of the printer, its what they need to print and cut, so ask them. Its not a style or design issue.